# Node.js Globals! The Bad, The Ugly & The Perfomance

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, global-variables

I'm quite new at node and trying to learn the best practices, writing a chat bot and there quite a few functions and variables that are reused a lot so it makes sense(at least to me) to use globals to avoid re-writing the same thing over and over.

To avoid some of the problems of globals I created a file called ... globals.js that contains all the globals, less prone to make mistakes if they are all in once place.

```
//globals.js
const Settings = require('./settings.js) // DB Model

...

// A few variables
global.foo = bar;
...
// I expect to have about 10-20 functions
global.baz = function(foo,bar) {
 ...
}

// Prepare and Load Settings
Settings.find(
    function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Unable to load settings: ' + err);
            process.exit(1);
        } else {
            for (let key in result[0].toObject()) {
              // All settings will be available globbaly
              global[key] = result[0][key];
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Those Settings have to be available to the entire project as different files will use most of them and I expect to have over 50 configurable settings, that's at least 50 globals. Is this a bad idea, should I instead just load the settings for each file that uses them instead of loading them as globals ?

Does having this many globals or more affect performace, is there a better way to achieve what I'm trying?

Thanks for taking the time to read this, any feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could keep all constants in single file, achieving the same result as with your globals, plus you will ensure that these constants are not leaked everywhere else.

Constants could be just a standard file, lets say **constants.js**:

```
module.exports = {
  VALUE1: 1,
  VALUE2: 2 //etc
}
```

Everywhere else where its needed, you just require this file:

```
const constants = require('./constants.js)
let neededHere = constants.VALUE1
```